# An Outlaw gets Married. Where should the Origin Token be placed now?

Tags: tales-of-arabian-nights

A player had the Outlaw status with the Origin token placed in a city and she also had the Married status.

What do we do with the Origin token in a case like that?

Comment: Your second question seems completely unrelated to the first - please remove it here and ask it as a separate question.

Comment: When that second question was removed already, adding it back seems an extremely poor decision, and wasn't justified in summary either. Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

From [this FAQ document provided by the game publishers](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/tales_of_the_arabian_nights_faq.pdf),

> If some other game effect forces you  to  move your Destination or Origin marker, you lose the effect (i.e. the status) associated with that marker!

When the player became Married, and moved the Origin Token, they lost their Outlaw status.

The Origin Token goes in the location which resulted in the Married status.